# WCF Additional Proxy Classes

Tags: wcf, class, inheritance, proxy

I have a WCF webservice that has the following service contract

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.org")]
public interface IEquinoxWebservice
{
    [OperationContract]
    Guid Init();

    [OperationContract]
    List<Message> Dequeue(Guid instanceId);

    [OperationContract]
    void Enqueue(Guid instanceId, Message message);

    [OperationContract]
    void Dispose(string instanceId);
}
```

Message class is an abstract class that is implemented by a bunch of concrete message classes.

I want to make all the concrete message classes available in the client proxy that is generated. Not just the message class.

Is there any way to make them available as types in the webservice so the standard Visual Studio proxy generator will create them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify those types. See [Data Contract Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx).